# Replacing German umlauts inside a specific attribute in heading HTML tags

Tags: java, regex

I have a large HTML file with many lines like

```
<h1 id="anwendungsfälle-und--funktionen">Anwendungsfälle und -funktionen</h1> 
<h1 id="öl">Öl</h1>
```

I need to replace all umlaut characters (ü,ö,ä) but only those between <> brackets (so only for header id, nowhere else.

```
<h1 id="anwendungsfaelle-und--funktionen">Anwendungsfälle und -funktionen</h1> 
<h1 id="oel">Öl</h1>
```

Ids may contain numbers, single and double - charcters. I have run out of ideas how to build a Java regex to match these ids.

I have tried something like

```
(<h)\d\s(id=")[A-Za-z0-9]*([-]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]*)*(">)
```

but this does not work (I know it's not Java regex, just an example).

Comment: Have you considered a solution not including regex? Parsing HTML via regex has proven to be... [suboptimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Here is one to start: `s.replaceAll("(\\G(?!^)|<h\\d+\\s+id=\")([^\"]*?)[üöä]", "$1$2")`

Comment: What about the upper case umlauts (Ä,Ü,Ö) and ß? There are not supposed to occour in an id?

Comment: This is the first thing that came to my mind. I'd love a simpler solution, if there is one. All ids are lowercase with no ß, or at least I have not stumbled upon them.

Comment: Wiktor, this regex removes all umlauts, so from "ändern" makes "ndern". Close, but something is missing.

Comment: A simpler solution is JSoup and selecting all h1 elements for inspection and possible correction.

Comment: @kumesana I suspect OP used the `\d` after `h` for a reason: all heading tags should be processed, not just h1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `JSoup`:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html); // Init the DOM structure
Elements hs = doc.select("*[id]");   // Find all tags with `id` attribute
for(int i = 0; i < hs.size(); i++){  // Iterate through the tags 
    Element h = hs.get(i);           // Get the current element
    if (h.tagName().matches("h\\d+")) { // If its tag is a heading tag
        String new_val = h.attr("id").replace("ä", "ae").replace("ö", "oe").replace("ü", "ue");
        h.attr("id",new_val);  // Replace the id attribute with a new one
    }
}
System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

Or regex:

```
Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<String, String>();
dictionary.put("ä", "ae");
dictionary.put("ö", "oe");
dictionary.put("ü", "ue");
String s = "<h1 id=\"anwendungsfälle-und--funktionen\">Anwendungsfälle und -funktionen</h1> \n<h1 id=\"öl\">Öl</h1>";
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\G(?!^)|<h\\d+\\s+id=\")([^\"]*?)([üöä])").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(result, m.group(1) + m.group(2) + dictionary.get(m.group(3)));
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
// => <h1 id="anwendungsfaelle-und--funktionen">Anwendungsfälle und -funktionen</h1> 
// <h1 id="oel">Öl</h1>
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/9hPq00)

**Regex**

```
(\G(?!^)|<h\d+\s+id=")([^"]*?)([üöä])
```

See the [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/qsxe45/1).

- `(\G(?!^)|<h\d+\s+id=")` - Group 1: either the end of the previous match (`\G(?!^)`), or (`|`) the `<h`, 1+ digits, 1+ whitespaces, `id="` (see `<h\d+\s+id="`)
- `([^"]*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars, as few as possible, other than `"`
- `([üöä])` - Group 3: any single char defined in the set

To just match inside `<...>`, you may use a simpler regex: [`(\G(?!^)|<)([^<>]*?)([üöä])`](https://regex101.com/r/qsxe45/2).

**As with all regex that is used against a mark-up language, there may be edge cases (e.g. when `>` or `<` come unserialized or there are multiple attributes in different order) when this won't work. Only use it when you are sure of the data format you are working with.**

Answer (score -1):

Your regex needs to look like this:

```
(?<="\\Wid\\=\\\"[^\"]*)(ä)(?=[^\"]\\\"") // -> ae
(?<="\\Wid\\=\\\"[^\"]*)(ö)(?=[^\"]\\\"") // -> oe
(?<="\\Wid\\=\\\"[^\"]*)(ü)(?=[^\"]\\\"") // -> ...
(?<="\\Wid\\=\\\"[^\"]*)(Ä)(?=[^\"]\\\"")
(?<="\\Wid\\=\\\"[^\"]*)(Ö)(?=[^\"]\\\"")
(?<="\\Wid\\=\\\"[^\"]*)(Ü)(?=[^\"]\\\"")
(?<="\\Wid\\=\\\"[^\"]*)(ß)(?=[^\"]\\\"") // -> ss
```

Please realize, that this is not perfect. There might be edge-cases, in which this will fail.